# Adding a product to advanced stock management programmatically on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to assign certain products for be used with advanced stock management, it seems OK in the DB, but some things aren't ticked on the BO, I'm wondering if this might have any impact.

For example, when selecting shop groups and going on a product in the BO, I don't see "I want to use advanced stock management for this product" ticked, while the "depends on stock" radio button is correctly selected (and thus disabled since the checkbox if left untouched). I don't know if this is problematic or not for the stock of the product. If anyone had any input on this, it would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$warehouse = new Warehouse(1);
$stock_manager = StockManagerFactory::getManager();
foreach($prods as $prod)
{
    StockAvailable::setProductDependsOnStock($prod['id_product'], 1);
    if ($stock_manager->addProduct($prod['id_product'], 0, $warehouse, 1, 5, 0.1, 1))
    {
        StockAvailable::synchronize($prod['id_product']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StockAvailable::setProductDependsOnStock` doesn't enable the AdvancedStockManagement for that product. You also need to set the product AdvancedStockManagement. You can use:

```
$warehouse = new Warehouse(1);
$stock_manager = StockManagerFactory::getManager();
foreach($prods as $prod)
{
    $product = new Product($prod['id_product']);
    if(!$product->advanced_stock_management)
        $product->setAdvancedStockManagement(true);
    StockAvailable::setProductDependsOnStock($prod['id_product'], 1);
    if ($stock_manager->addProduct($prod['id_product'], 0, $warehouse, 1, 5, 0.1, 1))
    {
        StockAvailable::synchronize($prod['id_product']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I have to save the product in my loop too? Doesn't it only set the checkbox in the Quantity tab (the only that enables you to choose whether or not to use manual or warehouse quantities)? If so, I'm not sure how useful it would be.

Comment: adding the check if advanced_stock_management is already enabled for that product is better, as you said. when you call setAdvancedStockManagement it will save the field advanced_stock_management, i think there is no need to call save again.

Answer (score 0):

For complete keeping record in Advanced Stock Management you should add also assign certain warehouse to product.

```
$warehouse_location = new WarehouseProductLocation();
$warehouse_location -> id_product = $prod['id_product'];
$warehouse_location -> id_product_attribute = 0; // need to be set if necessary
$warehouse_location -> id_warehouse = **$id_warehouse**;
$warehouse_location -> location = '';
$warehouse_location -> save();
```

This is missing in @sadlyblue answer code.

So full working code can be something like this:

```
// set variables
$msg = [];
$err = [];

$out_of_stock = 2; // 0 = deny, 1 = allow, 2 = by default
$id_warehouse = 2; // 1, 2, ...
$prods = [
    [
        'id_product' => 14,
    ],
    
];

$warehouse = new Warehouse($id_warehouse);
$stock_manager = StockManagerFactory::getManager();

foreach ($prods as $prod) {
    $product = new Product($prod['id_product']);

    if (!$product->advanced_stock_management) {
        $product->setAdvancedStockManagement(1);
    }
        
    StockAvailable::setProductDependsOnStock($prod['id_product'], 1);
    StockAvailable::setProductOutOfStock($prod['id_product'], $out_of_stock); //idProduct, outOfStock, idShop, idProductAttribute

    if ($stock_manager->addProduct(
        $prod['id_product'], // idProduct (int)
        0,                   // idProductAttribute (int)
        $warehouse,          // warehouse data by warehouse id (array)
        123,                 // quantity (int)
        1,                   // idStockMvtReason (int)
        0.0,                 // priceTe (float)
        1                    // isUsable (bool)
    )) {
        StockAvailable::synchronize($prod['id_product']);

        $warehouse_location = new WarehouseProductLocation();
        $warehouse_location -> id_product = $prod['id_product'];
        $warehouse_location -> id_product_attribute = 0; // need to be set if necessary
        $warehouse_location -> id_warehouse = $id_warehouse;
        $warehouse_location -> location = '';
        $warehouse_location -> save();

        $msg[] = 'Product ID:' . $prod['id_product'] . ' set to Advanced Stock Mmanagement';
    } else {
        $err[] = 'Unable to set product ID:' . $prod['id_product'] . ' to Advanced Stock Mmanagement';
    }
}
```

I used it in my project, it works same in Thirtybees.